# I am trying to put a where clause into a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table from a questionnaire that looks like the below. Instead of having it range from 1 - 5 i want it to range from 5-1 but only for the specific question id.

I have tried

```
where question_id = 24
case
  when value = 1 then '5'
  when value = 2 then '4'
  when value = 4 then '2'
  when value = 5 then '1'
end

        id  id_external text               value    question_id
1       42  10          Strongly Agree     1            24
2       43  11          Agree              2            24
3       44  12          Neutral            3            24
4       45  13          Disagree           4            24
5       46  14          Strongly Disagree  5            24
6       47  15          I Don't Know       999          24
```

I want the table to show as:

```
        id  id_external text               value    question_id
1       42  10          Strongly Agree     5            24
2       43  11          Agree              4            24
3       44  12          Neutral            3            24
4       45  13          Disagree           2            24
5       46  14          Strongly Disagree  1            24
6       47  15          I Don't Know       999          24
```

Comment: A "where clause" is not part of a CASE expression. A CASE expression uses the WHEN keyword. And CASE expressions can include another CASE expression; CASE expressions can be nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use when   condtion and  condition
 you can use when   condtion and  condition

```
    case when question_id = 24  AND value = 1 then '5' 
          when question_id = 24 AND value = 2 then '4' 
          when question_id = 24 AND value = 4 then '2' 
          when question_id = 24 AND value = 5 then '1'  
          when question_id <> 24 AND value = 1 then '1' 
          when question_id <> 24 AND value = 2 then '2' 
          when question_id  <> 24 AND value = 4 then '4' 
          when question_id <> 24 AND value = 5 then '5'  
          when  value = 3 then '3'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` expressions can be nested.  (A CASE expression is an *expression*, it's not a *statement*. A CASE expression can appear most anywhere any expression can appear.

Doesn't look like a SQL "where clause" has anything to do with the question being asked. The syntax for a a CASE expression includes WHEN as a keyword, not WHERE.

It looks like we want to return a column but use a *different* expression when question_id is 24. We can use a CASE expression to do that, in the SELECT list like this:

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.id_external
      , t.text
      , t.question_id
      , t.value AS orig_value
      , CASE
          WHEN t.question_id = 24 
          THEN expr1 
          ELSE expr2 
        END AS val
   FROM ...
```

Now we can substitute *expr2*... when question_id is other than 24, we can return `t.value`.

And for *expr1*, we could invert 1/5, 2/4, 4/2, 5/1 using an expression like

```
CASE WHEN t.value IN ('1','2','4','5') THEN 6 - t.value ELSE t.value END
```

So putting that all together, nesting CASE expressions:

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.id_external
      , t.text
      , t.question_id
      , t.value AS orig_value
      , CASE
          WHEN t.question_id = 24 
          THEN CASE 
                 WHEN t.value IN ('1','2','4','5')
                 THEN 6 - t.value 
                 ELSE t.value 
               END 
          ELSE t.value
        END AS val
   FROM ...
```